# как выровнять форму по высоте чтобы 3 input слева были равны 4-ой textarea справа?

Tags: html, css

как сделать чтобы 3 input слева были одним под одним с интервалом, а справа текстареа с учетом высоты а под текстарея кнопка

```css
.wrap_contact_inner{
    width: 48%;
    margin: 1%;
    float: left;
}
.bgf {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 8% 5%;
}
.wrap_contact_inner{
    height: 220px;
}
.bgfm{
    width: 90%;
    padding: 8% 5% 52% 5%;
}
.contact_home{
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.name_text_fild, .phone_text_fild{
    margin-bottom: 6%;
}
```

```html
 <form id="contact_form" method="POST" action="/send">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="wrap_contact_inner">
                                <div class=" fields_home name_text_fild"> 
                                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" class="name-text bgf" placeholder="{{trans('page.Your Name')}}:">
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Box -->

                                <div class="fields_home phone_text_fild ">
                                  <input type="text" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}" class="phone-text bgf" placeholder="{{trans('page.Telephone')}}:">
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Box -->

                                <div class=" fields_home phone_mail"> 
                                  <input type="text" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" class="email-text bgf" placeholder="{{trans('page.Email')}}:">
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Box -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="wrap_contact_inner">
                                <div class=" fields_home_mess">
                                    <textarea name="message" value="{{ old('message') }}" class="mesage-text bgfm" placeholder="{{trans('page.Message')}}:"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Box -->

                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <input type="submit" value="{{trans('page.Send')}}" class="button medium black form_elem" />
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#">
        <h3>Have a question</h3>
            <div id="left">
                <input type="text" class="n" placeholder="Your Name:">
                <input type="text" class="n" placeholder="Telephone">
                <input type="text" class="n" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Message" id="textarea"> 
                <input type="button" value="Send" id="button">
            </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    float: left;
}

#left > input {
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
}

#right {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#textarea 
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 151px;
    display: block;
}

#button {
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 208px;
    height: 40px;
}


form {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```